# How avoid typedef?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

```
template <class VertexType>
class GraphMatrix
{
};

template <class GraphType>
class Graph
{
 typedef typename GraphType::VertexType VertexType;
 GraphType* graph_;
 void addVertex(VertexType vertex)
 {
 }
 //...
};
int main()
{
    Graph <GraphMatrix <int> > graph;
    return 0;
}
```

See if I would add `typedef VertexType VertexType;//A` line to `GraphMatrix` `class` this code will pass compilation and will work, otherwise it gives compile error. Error:C2039: 'VertexType' : is not a member of 'GraphMatrix'. My question is follows 'is there a way (syntax) to make above code work without adding this stupid line `//A`'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always write the fully qualified name of `VertexType`, the `typedef` is merely a shortcut for you, which brings that name into scope and lets you write cleaner code.

So, **no** in this circumstance, there is no other way.

When using inheritance however you can `using BaseClass::something` to bring it into *scope*.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is follows 'is there a way (syntax) to make above code work without adding this stupid line //A

I don't think so.

However there are a few problems with your code. `GraphType` is a dependent-name and to indicate that `GraphType::VertexType` is a type you need to add [`typename`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names/613132#613132) before it.

However when the class template is instantiated for `GraphType = GraphMatrix <int>` the compiler couldn't find `GraphMatrix <int>::VertexType` so you get another error.

So in order to fix the errors change the definition of `GraphMatrix` to

```
template <class TVertexType>
class GraphMatrix
{
    public:
    typedef TVertexType VertexType;    
};
```

or something similar.

Complete working code [here](http://ideone.com/i53Ag0)

Comment: Oh I just have forgotten about typename. This is the cause of that I have not copy-past my code, but write here - in forum textarea :)
So as I understand from all answers there is no way to avoid typedefing in GraphMatrix. Thanks to all for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the argument of a templated class passed by a template-parameter, you must confine the allowable types for `GraphType`. You do this by specialization:

```
template <class GraphType>
class Graph;

template <template <class> class GraphType, class VertexType>
class Graph<GraphType<VertexType> >
{
  ... // use GraphType<VertexType> as your graph, VertexType as your vertex type
};
```

You can even [create a helper struct that will unpack the args for you](http://ideone.com/LvVhG):

```
template <class T> struct get_arg;

template <template <class> class Tpl, class Arg>
struct get_arg<Tpl<Arg> >
{
  typedef Arg type;
};
```

Note however, that this solution is quite inflexible - it only allows templates with one parameter as arguments for your `Graph` class template (imagine what you would have done if you added a parameter to your `GraphMatrix` template). So it is not normally used.

The ordinary solution is either adding typedefs to your classes (as you do with your "stupid line"), or even better, using traits classes and specializing these.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt so.

From the point of view of the `Graph` template, the `GraphType` template parameter is just a type name (so in this case, "a class"). So if `Graph` is instantiated with `GraphType = GraphMatrix<int>`, then `Graph` cannot even check whether it has received a template instance or a "regular" class. Therefore, it cannot access its template parameters - because `GraphType` doesn't even need to have any template parameters.

Introducing the typedef into `GraphType` enriches every instance of template GraphMatrix with the public information about the exact type it was instantiated with - which is exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not true - `Graph` can check that `GraphType` is a template with one parameter through specialization.

Comment: But shouldn't - it's better for an implementation to rely on a constract "I'm going to be instantiated with classes which have a typedef `VertexType`" than "I'm going to be instantiated only with template classes which always happen to have their first template parameter as a VertexType". Using specialization here seems hackish to me and violates the least astonishment principle, IMHO. I rest my case.